# typescript: deconstruct object with rest and types

Tags: typescript, types, spread

The interpreter says that `humanProps` is of type `humanProps: {humanProps: IHumanProps}`.

How can I set the type for the spread correctly so that `humanPros` has the type `IHumanProps`?

Example:

```js
interface IName {
  name: string
}

interface IHumanProps {
  hobby: string,
  age: number
}

interface IHuman extends IName, IHumanProps {}

const human: IHuman = {
  name: 'Linda',
  hobby: 'reading',
  age: 99
}

const { name, ...humanProps }: { name: string, humanProps: IHumanProps } = human;

console.log(name);
console.log(humanProps);
```

How can I deconstruct an object with the spread operator and specify the types? I couldn't find any information online about this specific case.

**[Edit]:**
The exact error I was receiving was that VSCode (or maybe rather the linter) were saying that the deconstructed `humanProps` were not of the type `IHumanProps` but rather of type `{humanProps: {humanProps: IHumanProps}}`, which is not correct. I assume this could be have been an issue with VSCode/ESLint.
Thank you all for the fast responses!

Comment: You are writing wrong, the const `human` is missing a value, you are annotating the type with the `:` syntax. Also, is `IHuman` not used??

Comment: You have fundamental syntax errors in that code (the `: {` after `const human` and the first colon in the last line). If you fix them, `name` is a string and `humanProps` is an object matching `IHumanProps`: https://tsplay.dev/N54Dow. That means it **is** an `IHumanProps`, since TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal. So, it's what you want.

Comment: (Well, the second error isn't as of the `:`, but you end up trying to explicitly apply a type to `humanProps`, which doesn't do what you want it to do. Just removing that part does, as I showed above.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the link does not work @T.J.Crowder 
But I assume you are saying to keep the second part implicit:
`const { name, ...humanProps }: { name: string } = human;`?

Comment: @lukas_o - Would you be more specific about how it "does not work"? It runs and produces the correct result, so...? But yes, keep it implicit -- not just the second part, exactly as I had it in the example: `const { name, ...humanProps } = human;`. The result is that (again) *"...name is a string and humanProps is an object matching `IHumanProps`..."* and that's fine, because (again) *"...TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal..."* That is, it's based on the *shapes* of types, not their names. So...

Comment: ...the type `{ hobby: string; age: number; }` is `IHumanProps`, even if the name isn't displayed when you hover the variable. The whole "structural vs. nominal" thing is a big thing to grasp about TypeScript (and a bit foreign if you come to it from [say] Java or C#). It's covered in multiple places on SO, [these answers](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+is%3Aanswer+structural+nominal) are some of them. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to rewrite the types to be more clear

```js
type Name = {
  name: string;
}

type HumanProps = {
  hobby: string;
  age: number;
}

type Human = Name & HumanProps;

const human: Human = {
  name: 'Linda',
  hobby: 'reading',
  age: 99
}
```

Now, in order to destruct the `human` object you simply have to do the following

```js
const {name, ...humanProps} = human
```

Comment: That's all they have to do with what they already have, too. Rewriting the types doesn't change that. The fundamental problem they have is the `:` in the `const` and trying to explicitly apply a type to the rest target.